# Python WTFORMS - Creating Textfield like FirstName On Background image

Tags: python, image, flask-wtforms

I am able to create a form with firstname, lastname etc. Now I am trying to insert a background image and the form should appear on the image. But When I put image in static, I can see background image and the textboxes goes down after the image.
How do I make the boxes on the image. Please help with the sample code.

Comment: You need to show your current code here. Preferably a minimised example that focuses exactly on the problem.

Comment: This is my html page with the background picture and some text fields. <br/>   {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<html>
<head>
<title>WTForms</title>

<img src=" {{ url_for('static', filename='images/ded.jpg') }}">


</head>
<body>

     <form method="POST" action="/">

      {{ form.csrf_token }}
      {{ render_field(form.FirstName) }}
      {{ render_field(form.LastName) }}
      {{ render_field(form.Company) }}
      {{ render_field(form.Location) }}
     <input type="submit" value="Enter">
     </form>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Sorry for the bad code paste but this gives me a background picture on the top and my text fields on the bottom. How can I have the textfields on the picture ?Hope it is clear.